# how to create UDF for Strembuilder's stream value in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a UDF for stream builder's stream value

this is my code without UDF

```
child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("chatrooms")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

now I want to change with udf but don't know what's return type should i take...

want to convert as following

```
child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myudf(),// this is what I want to create
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

```
void myudf()//pls correct me ,udf type
{
//what return type should I apply for this myudf function and what to implement in body
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("chatrooms")
              .where("participants.${widget.usermodel.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
              .snapshots(),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Stream return type

```
Stream myudf()//pls correct me ,udf type
{
//what return type should I apply for this myudf function and what to implement in body
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("chatrooms")
              .where("participants.${widget.usermodel.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
              .snapshots(),
}
```